# How to find the base of an infinite series?

Tags: probability

$$P(k)=\frac c{a^k},k=2,3,4,5,6,\dots$$
Isn't the base of this infinite series $1/a$? I been trying to find the probability of the odd outcome using 1st term/1-base, but I keep getting the wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all we must have$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{c}{a^k}=1$$here we must have $|a|>1$ therefore:$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{c}{a^k}=\dfrac{c}{a(a-1)}=1$$After that we have:$$P_{Odd}=c(\dfrac{1}{a^3}+\dfrac{1}{a^5}+\dfrac{1}{a^7}+...)=\dfrac{c}{a^3}(1+\dfrac{1}{a^2}+\dfrac{1}{a^4}+...)=\dfrac{c}{a(a-1)(a+1)}=\dfrac{1}{a+1}$$

Comment: Don't you mean $|a|>1?$  Is that really the sum of the series?

Comment: Of course :)   Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, I meant a>!. I figured out that c is a(a-1), but I have no idea how to find the probability of an odd outcome since I do not know what the base of the series is.

Comment: Then you need to calculate the following:$$P_{Odd}=c(\dfrac{1}{a^3}+\dfrac{1}{a^5}+\dfrac{1}{a^7}+...)$$

Comment: How do I find what the base is? I know you can simplify that to 1st term which is 1/a^3 divided by (1-base). Would the base in this case be 1/a?

Comment: It's $\dfrac{1}{a}$ when calculating for $c$ and $\dfrac{1}{a^2}$ when calculating for the requested probability since we are ignoring even numbers

Comment: ohh, I see. Thank you very  much!